# What causes the BBC News site to scroll up like this?

Tags: mobile-safari, websites

On both my iPhone and iPad (both up to date with iOS/iPadOS 14.3), if I am browsing [BBC News](http://bbc.co.uk/news) in Safari, whenever I browse back to the main page the browser window immediately scrolls straight back up to the top. This is the only site it happens on.

[Video showing problem.](https://u.pcloud.link/publink/show?code=XZyQ3YXZNTCOUFPbrTVDFhj7aEYlV8u0PVDk)

It’s been doing this since at least the release of iOS 13, and I filed a bug report with Apple some time ago but obviously nothing has changed.

Given the popularity of the site, I am surprised not to find any other references to this problem on the web but I would be amazed to find this only affects me. What would be causing it? I am assuming it is a problem with the way the site is coded, but what?

Comment: I think this is just how the site is supposed to work. It does the same for me.

Comment: @X_841 Why would it be by design? What advantage is it to users? Every site would do it if it was a good idea.

Comment: I am not the engineer behind it so I can't tell you. I can tell you that the behavior is the same across all my devices. My only suspicion is that BBC always wants you to see the latest news.

Comment: Anyone finding this late - it was either a bug or a poor feature, now seems to be fixed as of mid 2022.

Comment: @Tetsujin it stopped doing it for me for a while (c.ios15?) but, unless it’s literally stopped doing it today, it’s still a problem for me.

Comment: Not seen it happen in a while, though I do tend to use Apple News more often these days, so I may just not have been irritated by it so much.

Comment: @Tetsujin nope, still does it. Sometimes (seemingly if I swipe back very slowly) I manage to preserve my place on the previous page, but certainly not the majority of the time.